# porting emcraft stm-som uclinux on my board

Tags: kernel, load, u-boot, jtag, uclinux

I'm trying to run uclinux on my custom board which uses stm32f429. the configurations of this board looks like to stm-som board. So I downloaded the tree and installed u-boot on my board. Now I have a trouble with kernel. I ran *make* and the rootfs.uimage is made now!
but it is 6.1Mb ( which is because of busy box that I don't need) while I'm counting on 2Mb flash of the processor!
the second problem is I have to use jtag to load *.bin* files on my board but I don't know on which address I must load the image. 
now I have 2 questions:

1. How can I decrease the footprin of kernel image(How to discard busybox or any other extra files)?
2. How can I load the image on my board (on which address)?

Edition 1
This is the story: 9 months ago,I got a project,they asked me to run uclinux on dico board,a guy named tmk had ported the kernel and u-boot for disco board and it is accessible [here](https://github.com/robutest) . I made the images and project was done.about 6 months ago I got another project, this time I was asked to run the same OS on their own board which has a 12 MHz oscilator,and uses bank1 SDRAM and uart 6. at first I tried to port the same images used in uslinux which I asked about them that night, then I found out STM-SOM board has an identical structure except in UART part which I used [this](http://emcraft.com/som/stm32f4-200/using-stm-uart-ports-in-linux) and solved it. now I have one big problem, the som board has a large NOR flash which my board doesn't.this new kernel size is more than 6 MB while I have only 2Mb flash memory. I wonder if there is a way to reduce the size or not?and if yes,how?BTW serial port of this board is not working right,and when the u-boot counts down to auto boot,the port sends garbage data and doesn't let me to enter boot environment to type commands like printenv or anything else.

Comment: @sawdust I'm sure you can help ,could you please?

Comment: I find it difficult to provide help to you because you either omit salient information, or the information that you do provide is ambiguous or even contradictory.  E.G. you *"downloaded the tree"*, and suddenly have U-Boot, kernel and rootfs ready to install.  The sizes of the kernel and rootfs are essentially determined by how they are configured, but of course you haven't provided any details about that.  BTW you do need BusyBox, unless you plan to write your own init code.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for your answer :)
I added the details after the "Edition1" in the question context.